# Cleanest way to remove and patch holes from this unused satellite dish on side of house?

Tags: siding

We have a satellite dish attached to the side of the house from the previous owner, and it's unused. As it's sort of an eyesore, we'd like to remove it. What is the best way to do this? It seems straight-forward to get it off the wall (it's at head-level), but what should we do with the holes left behind? I'm not sure what the composition of the siding is, or the composition of what is beyond the siding. What's the appropriate product for filling that hole? Also, the cable goes up under the gutter into the attic above the garage. It's possible I might be able to pull it up but I'll have to look at the access I have. I suppose I might be able to just cut it at the gutter level as well.  Looks like a simple job, but just want to make sure I've got the right idea before going out and buying supplies.
[image: dish on side]
[image: closeup]
[image: cable]

Comment: It is great if you can pull the cable out. The hole can be filled with expandable foam, then paint it over (if desired) after cleanup the excesses.

Comment: Instead of removing brackets from wall, just remove dish and replace with a planter or something.

Comment: @crip659 idea is a good one.  Side note: I recently took down a Dish dish.  The people at Dish sent me a box postage paid to send them some of the guts from the dish, which are recyclable for them.   If you are recycling inclined maybe DirectTV will do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you remove the dish you can simply fill the holes with silicone caulk. The key is to keep moisture and insects from getting under the siding. There are various colors to choose from. You're not going to get a perfect match but those holes aren't large so probably not a big deal.
The cable can be clipped off at the soffit or pulled out completely.

Comment: Thanks. Did it yesterday and it was simple.